# (Bottom sheets) Is it possible to update the hierarchy of the screen without modifying the actuall application's layouts?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a text message that I show as an animated view in a specific layout.
Nothing particular, just a textview inside a relative layout that I make appear and dissappear.
Problem: I need to show this popup in a large number of layouts.
Question: Is there a way to do this other than re-writing all the layouts?
I.e. is there a way I could make a textview appear as overlay in the bottom of my screen by modifying generically the current activity's view somehow after it is finished creating *without* needing to know the actual hierarchy?

Comment: all you need to do is to override setContentView, then inside it, inflate the original view wrap it around LinearLayout and add your stuff

Comment: @pskink:You mean do this per activity right? Is it possible to do this by having some generic code that modifies the android's final view? I think it creates a framelayout

Comment: you can create a base Activity class with overriden setContentView and extend this class in every Activity you want that feature

Comment: @pskink:Many of the activities I have to work on already extend other customized classes. Is there a way to do this e.g. via interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can.  Facebook does this with "chat heads", Here's a library to help but you can do the same thing manually (I use this to display fps across all screens in a little floating button)

https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView

Comment: If I understand the project correctly, the user needs to press to show something. So you also get coordinates from the user. I would not know the coordinates. Only know that I want it to be at the bottom of visible screen

Comment: Ah I see, maybe Flipboard's bottom sheet library can help you? https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet.

Comment: Actually the `bottomsheet` you linked suits my needs perfectly, but adding a whole library for a small text seems an overkill to me. Is it possible to somehow do this without the library?

Comment: Of course you can.  To be honest this is a very small library, its really just 4 java files.  Take a look at implementation if you'd like to reimplement.  https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet/tree/master/bottomsheet/src/main/java/com/flipboard/bottomsheet

Comment: Looks nice, but to use this, the requirement is to update all the relevant layout files to be nested in `<com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout`. If I do that I might as well add the textview I am using in the first place. I wanted to avoid that. But you understood what I need and the library is nice, so +1

Comment: if this works better for you, here is another implementation that does not take wrapping in a base layout.  https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet  (its a little bigger though).